# How to set different background images for dark and light mode? (flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to set different app background images for dark and light theme and I want them to change according to the system theme.

I am also using a flutter package [adaptive_theme: ^3.1.1](https://pub.dev/packages/adaptive_theme) to change between dark and light theme as per system mode.

my code for app background image:

```
return SafeArea(
  child: Container(
     decorarion: BoxDecoration(
       image: DecorationImage(
          image: AssetImage('/path'),
         ),
       fit: BoxFit.cover
    ),
    child: Scaffold(...),
  ),
);
```

#### How to implement the package I have to achieve my desired result or is there any other way around?

Comment: Hi! It seems late here, but you could use https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeExtension-class.html, just add there your image url)) I didn't test it yet, but it could be more clearer, when using images depending on theme)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably infer the right background like this.

```
Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.light ? AssetImage('/path/light') : AssetImage('/path/dark')
```